# Order by pairs of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a set of rankings, ordered by group and ranking:

```
Group | Rank
------------
  A   |  1
  A   |  2
  A   |  3
  A   |  4
  A   |  5
  A   |  6
  B   |  1
  B   |  2
  B   |  3
  B   |  4
  C   |  1
  C   |  2
  C   |  3
  C   |  4
  C   |  5
  D   |  1
  D   |  2
  D   |  3
  D   |  4
```

I want to interleave the groups, ordered by group and rank, **n rankings per group at a time** (here, n=2):

```
Group | Rank
------------
  A   |  1
  A   |  2
  B   |  1
  B   |  2
  C   |  1
  C   |  2
  D   |  1
  D   |  2
  A   |  3
  A   |  4
  B   |  3
  B   |  4
  C   |  3
  C   |  4
  D   |  3
  D   |  4
  A   |  5
  A   |  6
  C   |  5
```

I have achieved the desired result with loops and table variables (code pasted here because I got a non-descript syntax error in a SQL Fiddle):

```
CREATE TABLE Rankings([Group] NCHAR(1), [Rank] INT)

INSERT Rankings
VALUES 
('A',1),
('A',2),
('A',3),
('A',4),
('A',5),
('A',6),
('B',1),
('B',2),
('B',3),
('B',4),
('C',1),
('C',2),
('C',3),
('C',4),
('C',5),
('D',1),
('D',2),
('D',3),
('D',4)

-- input
DECLARE @n INT = 2 --number of group rankings per rotation
-- output
DECLARE @OrderedRankings TABLE([Group] NCHAR(1), Rank INT)

-- 

-- in-memory rankings.. we will be deleting used rows
DECLARE @RankingsTemp TABLE(GroupIndex INT, [Group] NCHAR(1), Rank INT)
INSERT @RankingsTemp 
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rank ORDER BY [Group]) - 1 AS GroupIndex,
  [Group],
  Rank
FROM Rankings
ORDER BY [Group], Rank

-- loop variables
DECLARE @MaxGroupIndex INT = (SELECT MAX(GroupIndex) FROM @RankingsTemp)
DECLARE @RankingCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @RankingsTemp)
DECLARE @i INT

WHILE(@RankingCount > 0)
BEGIN
  SET @i = 0;
  WHILE(@i <= @MaxGroupIndex)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @OrderedRankings
    ([Group], Rank)
    SELECT TOP(@n)
      [Group],
      Rank
    FROM @RankingsTemp
    WHERE GroupIndex = @i;

    WITH T AS (
      SELECT TOP(@n) *
      FROM @RankingsTemp
      WHERE GroupIndex = @i
    );
    DELETE FROM T

    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END
  SET @RankingCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @RankingsTemp)
END

SELECT @RankingCount as RankingCount, @MaxGroupIndex as MaxGroupIndex

-- view results
SELECT * FROM @OrderedRankings
```

How can I achieve the desired ordering with a set-based approach (no loops, no table variables)?

I'm using SQL Server Enterprise 2008 R2.

**Edit:** To clarify, I need no more than `n` rows per group to appear contiguously.  The goal of this query is to yield an ordering, when read sequentially, offers an equal representation (n rows at a time) of each group, with respect to rank.

Comment: divide rank by 2 round up as a new column then order by it then group then rank. 1/2 = 1 2/2=1 3/2=2 4/2=2 etc... `Ceiling(value)` I believe is the syntax or `Ceiling(rank/2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this...[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f746/6/0)

```
Order by
 Ceiling(rank*1.0/2), group, rank
```

Working fiddle above (column names changed slightly)

Updated: was burned by int math... .  should work now. forcing int to decimal by multiplying by 1.0 so implicit casting doesn't drop the remainder I need for ceiling to round correctly.

Comment: Nice!  A lot more elegant than my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks but this does not quite produce the desired result (see the edit on my question)

Comment: Just replace rank/2 with rank/n.  Actually, may want to use rank*1.0/n, otherwise it's using integer division.

Comment: Wow, that did it.  Simple and effective.  Thanks!

Comment: to handle n simply alter the 2 as needed though variable  but I'm guessing @jonathanWilson already got that part.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a relatively low number of ranks, this would work:

```
Order by
  case when rank <= n then 10
    when rank <= 2*n then 20
    when rank <= 3*n then 30
    when rank <= 4*n then 40
    when rank <= 5*n then 50 --more cases here if needed
    else 100 
  end
, group
, rank
```